SQL trigger can't use enviroment variable as runtime parameter
I'm trying to use a simple SQL trigger where I have two arguments: the table and the connection string. I'm trying to fetch the connection string from the enviroment variables but I'm getting the error:

CS0182: an attribute must be a constant expression

Any way I can fix this ?
[Function("WarningTrigger")]
public async Task Run(
        [SqlTrigger("[dbo].[SensorWarnings]", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("dbconnection"))] 
        IReadOnlyList<SqlChange<Model.SensorWarning>> changes,
        FunctionContext context)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("SQL Changes: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(changes));

    SensorDatabaseQuery query = new SensorDatabaseQuery();
    await query.GetData();
}         


You can't use an expression like Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("...") inside an attribute. Use something like [SqlTrigger("[dbo].[ToDo]", "myConnectionString")] where myConnectionString is the name of an app setting that contains the connection string for the database.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql-trigger?tabs=isolated-process%2Cpython-v2%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-csharp

What exactly do you mean by "leak the database"? It's the app setting name, not the connection string details. You can override it the Azure Portal.

No but it points to appsettings value right ? using neviroment variables is way easier when building to azure

Thanks @Rui Jarimba for the comment.
You don't need to pass Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable explicitly along with connection string in Sql trigger declaration as it is recommended to use  [SqlTrigger("[dbo].[SensorWarnings]", "dbconnection")]  wherein the value of dbconnection will be fetched from local settings file while local development and from app settings post deploying to function app.

Required. The name of an app setting that contains the connection string for the database containing the table monitored for changes. The connection string setting name corresponds to the application setting (in  local.settings.json  for local development) that contains the  connectionstring to the Azure SQL or SQL Server instance.

By looking at the error CS0182: an attribute must be a constant expression you would know that only constant expression is allowed in function declaration.
I believe, your intent is to fetch the connection string value from app settings which can be fulfilled just by adding the attribute name.
